# How can I get ASP.NET MVC 4 to accept routes that look like filenames?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, routes

I'm working on a custom routing extension for ASP.NET MVC4 that uses reflection to generate routes based on attributes applied to controllers. It's a fork of [Brandon Byars' RestMvc project](https://github.com/bbyars/RestMvc#readme) and I'm updating it for .NET 4.5.

The attraction is that it allows one to write controllers that describe their own routes, like so:

```
public class EchoController : RestfulController
{
    [Get("echo/{thingToEcho}.{format}", "echo/{thingToEcho}")]
    public ActionResult Echo(string thingToEcho, string format)
    {
        if (format == "xml")
            return new ContentResult
            {
                Content = string.Format("<echo>{0}</echo>", thingToEcho),
                ContentType = MediaType.Xml
            };

        return new ContentResult
        {
            Content = thingToEcho,
            ContentType = MediaType.PlainText
        };
    }

    public override ActionResult Options(string resourceUri)
    {
        SetAllowHeader(resourceUri);
        return new ContentResult {Content = "Options body goes here..."};
    }
}
```

I'm running into a problem with routes in the format

```
[Get("echo/{thingToEcho}.{format}", "echo/{thingToEcho}")]
```

The idea here is that the client can make a request such as `GET /echo/test.xml` and the controller can then return a response in xml format instead of plain text, as demonstrated in the EchoController above.

In my fork of th eproject, all the routes are being correctly generated, but the "echo/{thingToEcho}.{format}" route doesn't work and I just get a 404 page. The same request but without the ".xml" works correctly and echoes back the expected text, so it seems like the route handler is doing its job, at least partly.

I'm a bit inexperienced with these technologies but I think this may be bound up with the handlers that are registered in the `web.config` file. In Brandon's original code targetting .NET 3.5 and MVC3, he has the following handlers:

```
<handlers>
  <remove name="WebServiceHandlerFactory-Integrated"/>
  <remove name="MvcHttpHandler"/>
  <remove name="UrlRoutingHandler"/>
  <add name="MvcHttpHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="*.mvc" type="System.Web.Mvc.MvcHttpHandler, System.Web.Mvc, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
  <add name="UrlRoutingHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="UrlRouting.axd" type="System.Web.HttpForbiddenHandler, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
</handlers>
```

In my project, I wanted to get this working on top of the MVC4 basic Web App template, so I created a new MVC4 project and dropped Brandon's controller onto it. In the MVC4 web.config, the following handlers are registered:

```
<handlers>
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
</handlers>
```

Again, I haven't added these handlers, they are the defaults generated by the MVC4 project template.

Could this be the source of my problem? How would I solve this?

Comment: Update - I'm fairly convinced now that the problem is in the web.config and the IIS8 'extensionless' handlers. As soon as they see a URL that looks like a filename, they try to serve a file off disk and return a 404 when it is not there; the MVC stack is not even called. Currently, I'm not sure what to do about it.

Comment: OK, I've given up on the particular library I was using and I'm no longer using the '.format' notation to do content negotiation. I've decided to use ASP.NET Web API instead, and that does content negotiation through the Accept header.